# C++ Jupyter-lab

Tags: c++, jupyter-lab, xeus-cling

Installed miniconda, created env, trying to install xeus-cling -

```
conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge
```

Gives an error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

And so in a circle

Comment: Try using `mamba` instead of `conda`. Or try with a clean new environment.